Java Spring, не отображается сохраненная в базу данных информация в html странице
Пишу код для сдачи итогового задание по программированию.
Столкнулся с проблемой вывода информации из БД sql. При сохранении информации и изображения пользователем, вся информация сохраняется в бд.
НО проблема с тем, что эта информация просто не отображается на странице. Возможно код просто не выгружает сохраненную информацию на страницу.
Код с контроллера и html страницы
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/images")
public class ImageController {

    private final ImageService imageService;
    private final UserService userService;

    public ImageController(ImageService imageService, UserService userService) {
        this.imageService = imageService;
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @GetMapping("/upload")
    public String showUploadForm() {
        return "upload";
    }

    @PostMapping("/upload")
    public String uploadImage(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                              @RequestParam("name") String name,
                              @RequestParam("staname") String staname,
                              @RequestParam("year") Integer year,
                              @RequestParam("cost") Double cost,
                              Principal principal) {
        try {
            String userEmail = principal.getName();
            imageService.saveImage(file, name, staname, year, cost, userEmail);
            return "redirect:/users";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return "upload";
        }
    }

    @GetMapping
    public String listImages(Model model, Principal principal) {
        String email = principal.getName();
       User user = userService.findByEmail(email);

        if (user == null) {
            return "redirect:/login";
       }

        //List<Image> images = imageService.getImagesByUser(user);
        //model.addAttribute("images", images);
        //return "users";

        List<ImageDto> images = imageService.getImagesByUser(user).stream()
             .map(image -> new ImageDto(
                     image.getId(),
                       image.getImage(),
                        image.getName(),
                        image.getStaname(),
                        image.getYear(),
                        image.getCost()
               )).toList();

      model.addAttribute("images", images);
      return "users";    
    }
}

    <div class="row">
        <div th:each="image : ${images}" class="col-md-4 mb-4">
            <div class="card">
                <img th:src="@{'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + ${T(org.apache.tomcat.util.codec.binary.Base64).encodeBase64String(image.image)}}" 
         class="card-img-top" alt="Image">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text">
                        <b>Название:</b> <span th:text="${image.name}"></span><br>
                        <b>Марка:</b> <span th:text="${image.staname}"></span><br>
                        <b>Год:</b> <span th:text="${image.year}"></span><br>
                        <b>Стоимость:</b> <span th:text="${image.cost}"></span> 
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    
    <p th:each="image : ${images}">
        <span th:text="${image.name}"></span>
    </p>


Необходима более детальная информация. Что именно не отображается и где?
